# Poisson process and properties

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I consider a poisson process with random variable $N_t$. 
Now I look at following sum: $$\sum_{i=2}^k P(N_t = k-i)  \cdot P(N_h = i) \underbrace{=}_{1} \sum_{i=2}^k P(N_t = k-i)  \cdot o(h) \underbrace{=}_{2}   o(h) $$

How can I verify $ 1$ using the property $ P(N_h \geq 2 )= o(h)$ with $\frac{o(h)}{h} \rightarrow 0 $ for $ h \rightarrow 0$

Why is $2$ true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have definition: to check if smth is $o(h)$ you can divide it by $h$ and check whether it converges to zero at $h\to 0$.

(1) is true since for every $i\geq 2$ 
$$\mathbb P(N_h=i)\leq \mathbb P(N_h\geq 2)=\sum_{i=2}^k \mathbb P(N_h=i).$$ 
So 
$$
0\leq \frac{\mathbb P(N_h=i)}{h}\leq \frac{\mathbb P(N_h\geq 2)}{h} = \frac{o(h)}{h} \to 0 $$
as $h\to0$ and then $\mathbb P(N_h=i)=o(h)$.

(2) is true since $o(h)+o(h)=o(h)$. Moreover, $\mathbb P(\ldots)\leq 1$ and then
$$
0\leq \frac{\sum_{i=2}^k \mathbb P(N_t=k-i)\cdot o(h)}{h} \leq \frac{\sum_{i=2}^k 1\cdot o(h)}{h} =(k-1)\frac {o(h)}{h} \to 0
$$
as $h\to 0$ for any fixed $k$ and then $\sum\limits_{i=2}^k \mathbb P(N_t=k-i)\cdot o(h)=o(h)$.

In the inequality above I used that $o(h)$ is indeed a non-negative probability, so multiplying by it does not change sign of inequality.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you very much:)